# Как поменять местами строки со столбцами в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

Смотрите, у меня есть задание, выглядит оно следующим образом:

**Написать программу которая создаёт массив размером [256] элементов и
заполняет его случайным образом числами от 1 до 1000 . После этого
вывести все числа на экран в несколько форматированых столбцов , при
этом в первом столбце выводить числа в DEC формате , во втором в HEX
формате , в третьем в OCT формате, четвёртый опять в DEC и т.д. до
конца.**

Я создал двумерный массив, по идее в столбцах воспользовался манипуляторами и вывел этот двумерный массив измененным, но вместо того, чтобы выводиться первому столбцу в dec, второму в hex, а третьему в oct, так выводятся  строчки.
Помогите, пожалуйста, какие возможности есть поменять их местами, так чтобы все было правильно по заданию или по другому это сделать, буду очень благодарен. Мой код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#define N 64
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int arr[N][N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 1000 - 1;
            cout << setw(5) << arr[i][j]; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                cout << setw(5) << dec << arr[i][j];    
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
            else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            cout << setw(5) << hex << arr[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
            }
            else {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                cout << setw(5) << oct << arr[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;       
        }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто смотрите какой столбец и пишите.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Os -std=c++11 matdiv.cpp -o matdiv
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#define N 64
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int arr[N][N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 1000 - 1;
            cout << setw(5) << arr[i][j]; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int line = 0; line < 16; line++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < 16; column++) {
        switch  (column % 3) {
        case  0 :
          cout << setw(5) << dec << arr[line][column];    
          break ;
        case  1 :
          cout << setw(5) << hex << arr[line][column];
          break ;
        default :
          cout << setw(5) << oct << arr[line][column]; } } // column
        cout << endl; } // line      
    } // main
```

Comment: Очень ловко вы сделали, спасибо огромное, я бы до такого не догадался.